# android fragment reuse layout created in onCreateView again

Tags: android, layout, android-fragments

I create my layout in the onCreateView of the Fragment (say FragA) the first time it is called and store it in a member variable (say ViewA). Now I push another fragment (say FragB) on top of it and after some work press the back button. This causes the FragA'a onCreateView to be called again. Now if I return my saved member Variable (ViewA) then an exception is thrown saying 'The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first'. My question is that, is there no other way to re-use this layout without inflating a new instance

Answer (score 0):

I think yes, you need to create new instance, because you save the context in the fragment. This is the IllegaleStateException,for example you get the same exception if you called twice the *setContentView()* method.
Maybe you call *removeView()* or *removeAllViews()* it will works.